# Using Javascript to set input to readonly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use Javascript to set input fields to readonly, if they do not contain any value, i.e if they are null. this is my code, I'm not receiving any errors from the debugger, but it simply refuses to work, could someone

```js
//checkScore();
function checkScore(){
    document.getElementById('score_row1').readonly = true;
    var scores = document.getElementsByClassName("score_holder");
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<scores.length; i++){
        if(scores[i].value!=null){
            scores[i].readonly="readonly";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body onload="checkScore()">


        <table align="center" cellpadding="3">
            <tr valign="baseline">
                <td colspan="3" align="center" id="course_row25" value="EDU-101"><strong>EDUCATION COURSES</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <input name="course_row1" type="text" id="course_row1" title="EDU-101: Historical Foundation of Education" value="EDU-101" size="5" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="30" size="5" class="score_holder" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" id="course_row1" name="course_row1" value="EDU-101">
                    <input name="course_row1" type="text" id="course_row1" title="EDU-101: Historical Foundation of Education" value="EDU-101" size="5" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" size="5" class="score_holder" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" id="course_row1" name="course_row1" value="EDU-101">
                    <input name="course_row1" type="text" id="course_row1" title="EDU-101: Historical Foundation of Education" value="EDU-101" size="5" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="10" size="5" class="score_holder" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should be `readOnly`

Comment: `scores[i].readonly="readonly";` — The readonly DOM property is a boolean. It can have the values `true` and `false`. `"readonly"` works only because the string is cast to a boolean.

Comment: as @Quentin mentioned, regarding [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp) it is scores[i].readOnly=true;

Comment: @Quentin @ Petri I just adjusted my code to that, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no element with the id `score_row1` in your HTML, so your js will throw an error and fail.

Also the property is `readOnly` and not `readonly`

So this `scores[i].readonly="readonly";` should be `scores[i].readOnly="readonly";`

Created a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/kibatez/edit?output)

Answer (score 1):

The value of a text input will **always** be a string.

If nothing has been typed in it, then the value will be `""`. It will never be `null`.

Comment: noted, but what I'm trying to achieve is to set the input to readOnly. since none of the values are equal to null, that should imply that all the input fields would then be set to readOnly, but that's not the case